# Do spaces play a role in a CSS stylesheet or just for readability?

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning HTML with CSS, and I see many spaces in between the CSS stylesheet, I even tried removing those spaces and the sheet works perfectly. So what is the role of spaces?

Please check the example below:

```
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
}

p {
    color:green;
}
```

has same function as

```
body{background-color: lightgrey;}
h1{color: blue;}
p{color:green;}
```

Regards
Naser

Comment: As a side note; you can minify your css sources for performance

Comment: Thank you LGSon, but IMHO, the no spaces version looks easy to the eyes right?

HddnTHA, spaces do have an impact on overall size of the sheet right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is case sensitive, but CSS isn't space sensitive. There isn't a role for this, but generally is recommended use space. Why? Often is used this:

```
body {
   background-color: red;
}
```

It is called indentation, If you've a good indentation your code will be neater and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It is, as you said, just for readability. Your example may be readable, but for complex pages the amount of code written is huge and without spaces it will be difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

Spaces used in CSS is just to understand the complex codes because sometimes it is difficult for developer to differentiate between the code so thats why it is used.